# Bixby: want to implement stop watch in my capsule

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I want to display a stopwatch(timer) for my capsule.

So, is there any way from which I can show timer in my view page which will get refreshed every second.
I am not understanding where to start. How will time get refreshed?

Any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in **refresh** command to repaint the screen.  For example,

```
result-view {
  match {
    Activity (this) {
      min (Required)
      max (One)
      from-output: CheckRideShareStatus (check)
    }
  }
  message {
    if (this.countdown != 0) {
      template ("Your ride will arrive in #{value(this.countdown)} seconds.") 
    } else {
      template ("I hope you are enjoying your ride")
    }
  }
  refresh {
  if (this.countdown != 0) {
    spec {
      delay-seconds (5)
      with-request {
        intent {
          goal: CheckRideShareStatus
          value {
            $expr (this)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
  render {
    layout-macro (activity-map-macro) {
      param (activity) {
        expression (this)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The Bixby team has provided a working example on [Github](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection/tree/master/refreshing-content)

Detail on refresh [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/building-views.refresh)

Comment: Thank you for your response...is it possible to just refresh the "#{value(this.countdown)}" instead of refreshing the whole screen. Because I just wanted to show the dynamic countdown which I get from my API.

Comment: No, the refresh will repaint the entire screen every 'delay_seconds' interval.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's possible to do a 1 second refresh this is definitely going to suffer from inaccuracy due to latency.

Depending upon your use case, simply creating an animated gif and displaying it may be simpler and definitely more accurate. Perhaps this combined with a refresh may be a better solution.

An example (from https://timertopia.files.wordpress.com/2018/06/30seccut.gif) would be something like this

[image]

Comment: Roger makes a valid point.  If you're looking for a short count down '3-2-1', or a timer that doesn't need to be perfectly accurate, the refresh method will work.  You'll also have the ability to control the duration and stop of the refresh programmatically.  It will really depend on your use case.